# S3 and KMS interaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please explain who will request KMS Keys when we upload object to S3.Is it uploader or S3 itself ?

If S3 have to deal with the KMS it has to assume a role.

Or is S3 mention the uploader in the API request ?

[image: S3 and KMS interaction]

Comment: KMS is evolving. Changes are being made this month: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingKMSEncryption.html

Comment: @iohans as per the document, it is the S3 who makes the request ? But how it can do it with out a role assign to it ?